# Can Gnuplot handle png transparency?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using the `plot 'my_image.png' binary filetype=png with rgbimage` feature of gnuplot to superimpose images on a (scarce) scatterplot.

My png's have a transparent background, so I had been hoping that they could 'respect' the grid and axes, but unfortunately they are plotted on top of it with a white, opaque background.

Is there any ways to address this issue ?

#### Minimal working example

The file 2091450.png is provided by [First Google result for Transparent PNG](http://i35.tinypic.com/2091450.png) :

```
set terminal pdfcairo font "CMU Serif" linewidth 4 rounded \
fontscale 1.0 size 29.7cm, 21cm enhanced dashed
set output 'transparency_test.pdf'

set style line 81 lt rgb "#808080"
set style line 80 lt 0  # dashed
set style line 80 lt rgb "#808080"  # grey
set grid back linestyle 80

set border 3 back linestyle 81
plot '2091450.png' binary filetype=png origin=(0,0) dx=1.0 dy=1.0 with rgbimage
```

Comment: This page describes how to get a transparent background, and tells you some things that can go wrong: http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/transparency-in-gnuplot.html. Try the help command, `help transparent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things:

- Your links gives me only a jpg image despite the URL name (If it would be transparent, you would get only a completely black image as result with the `rgbimage` style).
- To plot images with transparency use the `rgbalpha` plotting style:

  ```
  plot 'transparencytest.png' binary filetype=png with rgbalpha
  ```

  I used the following file `transparencytest.png` for testing, which works fine:

  [image]
- Why don't you just put the grid and the border to the `front` layer?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case of an answer I couldn't solve initially because of an inappropriate Google search : looking for 'gnuplot png image transparency' was not productive at all, because all the keywords interacts with each others to yield different results.

But a search for 'rgbimage transparency' was much better because of reduced interference between words and led me to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot/yFoRzm80RFA) page with the appropriate result :

Instead of using `rgbimage`, simply use `rgbalpha`.